# Como controlar altura dentro de uma Grid?

Tags: html, css, div

Atualmente, estou com o código abaixo, gostaria de descer a `marca` e `meta` até o limite da linha vermelha, como posso move-los ?[image]

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color:white;
    background-size: cover;
}
.container {
    width: 380px;
    height: 160px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.container div {
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.rel, .acu {
    grid-column: span 2;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="marca">Marca</div> 
        <div class="meta">Meta</div>
        <div class="rel">Realizado</div>
        <div class="acu">Acumulado</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Você pode usar `.container .marca, .meta{align-items:flex-end!important;}` na `marca` e `meta` com
   `!important`
2. Ou ao invés de usar `.container div` para definir para todas as `div`, você coloca somente as classes que você quer que sejam iguais e separa as que você quer que sejam diferentes.

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color:white;
    background-size: cover;
}
.container {
    width: 380px;
    height: 160px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.container .marca, .meta {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:flex-end;
}
.container .rel, .acu {  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.rel, .acu {
    grid-column: span 2;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="marca">Marca</div> 
        <div class="meta">Meta</div>
        <div class="rel">Realizado</div>
        <div class="acu">Acumulado</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```